# SQL Case WHERE condition, if condition passes check if value is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I cannot figure out how to add the last condition.
This is part of dynamic code + cursor. Cursor consists of a list of table columns. I am comparing values in two tables that are identical in their structure, joining them on PK, and checking one column at a time where the values are not matching.
What I need in my last condition is:

- if @columnName is 'untCode'
- then I want to exclude those rows where TMC.untCode is null
- otherwise this condition does not apply

```
    DECLARE @columnName CHAR(10) = 'untcode';
    
    SELECT MC.@columnName, TMC.@columnName 
    FROM dbo.firstable AS TMC
    INNER JOIN dbo.secondtable AS MC
        ON MC.ID = TMC.ID
        AND MC.Code = TMC.Code        
    WHERE MC.ID = 123
    AND TMC.@columnName<> MC.@columnName
    --How do I add this??
    AND TMC.@columnName CASE 
        WHEN @columnName='untCode' THEN not null 
        ELSE --What???
        END ;
```

Appreciate the help

Comment: `MC.@columnName` is never going to work; you cannot use a variable to replace a literal. We need more details here; what are you actually trying to achieve? Supply sample data and expected results.

Comment: True, I just did not want to overcomplicate the question with things like ```ISNULL(CAST(TMC.' + @ColumnName + ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)), ''VALUEISNULL'') AS SQL' + @ColumnName
            + '```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said it:

```
    --How do I add this??
    AND NOT (@columnName='untCode' AND TMC.untCode is NULL)
```

or with a slight change:

```
    --How do I add this??
    AND (@columnName<>'untCode' OR TMC.untCode is NOT NULL)
```

But you should correct `AND TMC.@columnName<> MC.@columnName` as @Larnu said; did you mean AND TMC.columnName=MC.columnName`?

Comment: Your suggestion worked, thank you!

The 2nd part, it is dynamic code with ' + @columnName + ' but I thought it would be too messy to paste everything.

Comment: Glad to hear; could you choose as answer then?